How do I deploy a Nuxt 3 solution to an Azure Node Web App
For the last few days I've been trying to configure an Azure Web App using Node as runtime stack. All the guides out there talks about Static Web Apps but that does not suit my needs.
I use Github Actions to build and deploy the solution and all checkmarks are green in the end. The site however says ":( Application Error" and the diagnostic resources says:
The Resource '.../slots/gfecb4esg8r4dcc7' under resource group 'xxx' was not found.. Since I don't use slots I've tried to remove slot-name: 'Production' from the yaml file to no prevail, the error message stays the same.

What environment variables do I need to configure?
What do I put as Startup Command in the Azure Web App?
What do I put as the start command in package.json?
Am I missing something else?

Here is my yaml file content if necessary:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v4

            - name: Set up Node.js version
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                  node-version: "20.x"

            - name: npm install, build, and test
              run: |
                  npm install
                  npm run build --if-present
                  npm run test --if-present

            - name: Zip artifact for deployment
              run: zip release.zip ./* -r

            - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
              with:
                  name: node-app
                  path: release.zip

    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        environment:
            name: "Production"
            url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
        permissions:
            id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

        steps:
            - name: Download artifact from build job
              uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
              with:
                  name: node-app

            - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
              run: unzip release.zip

            - name: Login to Azure
              uses: azure/login@v2
              with:
                  client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_XXX }}
                  tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_XXX }}
                  subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_XXX }}

            - name: "Deploy to Azure Web App"
              id: deploy-to-webapp
              uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
              with:
                  app-name: "myapp"
                  # slot-name: 'Production'
                  package: .


Share your Azure App service Log stream here.

If possible, share your code?

@AsleshaKantamsetti I see no point in sharing the log stream since I don't know what to set as environment variables or startup commands in neither Azure nor package.json. First things first so to speak... In terms of source code it's not important, think of it as a hello world example.

I tried nuxtjs 3 sample code and deploy to azure web app through Vs Code and it is successfully deployed. See this image.

When I deployed through Git, I didn't find the .output folder in the Kudu console.

Thank you for your effort! I end up with the same result and I don't understand what is wrong since the .output folder is missing. I have tried to add "npm run build" in the Startup Command without knowing this is the way to go...? Still it does not work.

I will try from my side and let you know if I find any solution.

Thank you @AsleshaKantamsetti! Your comments made me look in the right direction and the culprit was .gitignore in combination with the build script. The build script ignored the .output folder since it is included in the .gitignore file. I changed the artifact command to run: zip -r release.zip .output/* and removed all settings in the Startup Command and the Internet is now a better place... ;)

Can I post it as an answer with details steps?

Please do! Go bananas!

I created sample nuxtjs app and even I got the Application error after deploying it to azure web app through GitHub.
The .output folder is not deployed to Azure through GitHub Actions, even though when we run the npm run build command in workflow file.

Workflow file might not include the .output folder in the deployment package. As .output is a hidden folder, we need to directly include it in packaging commands as following in workflow file.
run: zip -r release.zip .output/*


I added below Start script to package.json:
"scripts": {
"start": "nuxt start"
}

If you want to deploy the application smoothly, you can deploy it via VS Code Azure Extension. As it will add all files automatically.
Goto Azure Extension -> Subscription -> Select Azure Web App -> Right Click hit deploy to web app.

Azure Web App Output:


It's weird to have a build directory tracked in your git versioning IMO + images look broken.
